# UI5 set a table content density/margins independent of the rest of UI style

Tags: sapui5

In UI5 there are several pre-defined [density / margins](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e54f729da8e3405fae5e4fe8ae7784c1) modes.

Can I set for a table a compact content density (`sapUiSizeCompact`), while the rest of UI should continue to use `sapUiSizeCozy`? In the list of [`sap.m.Table`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Table#controlProperties) properties I can't find something like `class`/`style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.addStyleClass` should work for every control. I've tested `class` in XML and it works too.

XML:

```xml
<Table class = "sapUiSizeCompact" />
```

JS:

```js
this.byId("myTable").addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also opened an issue at UI5 Github, let's see what will the DevTeam say.